# Full screen nav menu block with avada theme

Tags: menus, themes, css

I have a menu structured exactly how I want it but I need the style to be a bit more refined and specific.

I'm using the avada theme with mega menu functionality, and I've applied it to the first link here:

http://watershedgeo.staging.wpengine.com/

However, I want my dropdown to be full width completely and house the dropdown options in a different style, like this:

https://www.mohawkgroup.com/

So for instance, If i hover over the main one, the full width block menu drops down and next sub headers would be below with any additional headers below that.

Is there a specific way to do this with avada theme and css?

Answer (score 1):

[Select the Full Width Mega Menu on/off selector in Avada settings](https://theme-fusion.com/avada-doc/header/mega-menu-width/).

Here's the steps to follow covered on that url:

> How To Set The Mega Menu To Full Width
>
> Step 1 – Go to WP Dashboard > Appearance > Menus, locate the first
>   level menu item and click the Avada Options button.
>
> Step 2 – Once the settings window has opened, locate and activate the
>   Fusion Mega Menu & Full Width Mega Menu settings as seen in the
>   example image for this section.
>
> Step 3 – Click ‘Save’ to close the Avada Options window and scroll to
>   the bottom and click “Save Menu” to save your changes made to the
>   menu.

I looked at your site code and your menu has a width of 960px set; Setting it to Full Width should fix this.

Comment: So, I have a slightly different panel but when I go to appearance > menus and select to level item, there's no avada options button but there are check boxes for fusion mega menu and full width menu. I have those selected and saved but it doesn't seem to have changed.

Comment: Are you on latest Avada version?